# Is there a macro to make std::optional::operator* throw on bad access?

Tags: c++, stdoptional

I mistakenly have dereferenced an uninitialized `std::optional` and only found out using valgrind (`Syscall param exit_group(status) contains uninitialised byte(s)`), like in this minimal working example:

```
#include<optional>
struct Foo {
    int i=1;
};

std::optional<Foo> bar(){
    return {};
}

int main() {
    return bar()->i;
}
```

What can protect me from these bugs?

Is there some macro/flag that I can define before `#include<optional>` in order to have at least a runtime error (make `std::optional` throw on *every* bad access or `assert(this->has_value())` )? I don't care about performance here and prefer defensive programming.

Comment: `optional::value` serves exactly that purpose. Why not just use this and ban/warn about asterisk operator using some linter, e.g. clang-tidy?

Comment: @alagner 1. Yes I will do this in future, actually I wrote the buggy code because I had assumed that optional does always throw and knowing the truth now, I thin I can live with this best practice (using `optional::value`).

Comment: @alagner 2. Do you have a link on this clang-tidy functionality (I don't know this capability yet). This would be great to check my existing code.

Comment: I'm afraid you might need to write it yourself:
https://blog.audio-tk.com/2018/03/20/writing-custom-checks-for-clang-tidy/

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, there is a ready-made check for it, please see the whole answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a language level I am not aware on any flags/switches that would allow you to achieve it. However, such places can be detected using clang-tidy. Contrary to what I initially thought, turns out there is a ready-made check for it called [`bugprone-unchecked-optional-access`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone/unchecked-optional-access.html)

Interestingly enough, it's smart enough to detect if the optional has been check before accessing it:

```cpp
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    x = bar()->i; //reports this
    if (auto z=bar(); z.has_value())  {
        x = z->i +1; //but not this
    }
    return x;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5shzvKKoh)

Comment: Hm... Might come with false positives if test and access are far apart in complex code.

Comment: @Aconcagua I'd be more afraid of false negatives tbh (e.g. lambdas mentioned in the docs). In a worst case scenario, false-postitves can always be nolinted away, but false-negatives can cause more hassle.

Comment: Depending on how strict the checks are (*any* unchecked access annotated?) false negatives appear rather unlikely to me...

Comment: Would suffice to annotate those between assignment and first test only – where passing by non-const reference or pointer would need to be considered as assignment (ignoring the fact that `const`-ness might be casted away in some scenarios...).